# Visual Studio 2019 Linux Docker Container Cannot Access SQL Server (on Network)

Tags: visual-studio, docker, networking, visual-studio-2019

I have used the template for a ASP.NET Core Web API Application running in Docker on Linux.

It seems to run fine until it needs to access my Sql Server (running on my network).  When it tries to do that I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

And the inner exception says:

> No such device or address

I have read that running docker with this command: `--net=host` can let your container access your network.  But I can't seem to find the way to make that work with Visual Studio's integrations (pressing F5 or the `> Docker` toolbar button to start running and debugging).

**How can I get networking going with Visual Studio, Docker and Linux?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my connection string.  When running on windows and IIS Express I could just put the server name in my connection string.

When running on a Linux container I needed the fully qualified domain name (fqdn) for the server name.

Once I did that, it worked fine.